# Why can't I use IIFE with "this"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My test code:

```
var colorChanged = function (c) {
  //valid syntax:
  (function (x) {
    x.css('color', '#f00')
  })($('.' + c));

  //invalid syntax:
  (function (this) { //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this        
    this.css('color', '#f00')
  })($('.' + c));  
};

<div class="demo">Div text</div>
<button onclick="colorChanged('demo')">Change color</button>
```

I'd reference [Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) but it didn't mention about using `this` in this case.

My question is: Is there any way to use `this` as an element (`this = $('.' + c)`) in the example?

Comment: Why on earth would you use the protected `this` keyword as the name of an argument, it's like doing `var this = 'myself'`

Comment: `this` is a keyword. It cannot be used as a variable name. You'll get the same syntax error if you do `(function(if){})` or `(function(function){})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to use `this` inside your IIFE's, you can bind the `thisValue` with `bind()` before calling the IIFE.

```
(function() {
    this.css('color', '#f00')
}).bind($('.' + c))();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bind() or call() or apply() and pass 'this' through them as your scope changed for 'this'...

It's always a good practice using these functions in javascript, rather then attach it to the function...

The best option is call for your code...

```
(function() {
    this.css('color', '#f00')
}).call($('.' + c));
```

Also using click handler in your javascript, make your code much cleaner and can make your coding structure better, you also can use multiple selection in jQuery to keep HTML clean if needed more selectors handle this function...

Comment: ya. It's just only a demo. Thanks for the answer :)